# How to style HTML element tags in MUI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the latest MUI version (v5) and `CssBaseline` from [@mui/materials](https://mui.com/) and given how I normally do this in CSS:

```
body, html, #root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 62.5%; /* makes 1.2rem === 12px, 1.6rem === 16px, ect... */
  text-align: left;
}
```

### MUI Body

(add the following to my theme)

```
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: {
        body: {
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          minHeight: '100%',
          margin: 0,
          padding: 0,
          fontSize: '62.5%', // makes 1.2rem === 12px, 1.6rem === 16px, ect...
          textAlign: 'left'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

### MUI Root

(add the following to my sxStyle e.g: `sx={{...sxLayout, ...sxLayout.root}}`)

```
const sxLayout = {
  flexDirection: 'column',
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    minHeight: '100%',
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
    fontSize: '62.5%', // makes 1.2rem === 12px, 1.6rem === 16px, ect...
    textAlign: 'left',
    '&': {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      minHeight: '100%',
      margin: 0,
      padding: 0,
      fontSize: '62.5%', // makes 1.2rem === 12px, 1.6rem === 16px, ect...
      textAlign: 'left'
    },
    '&.MuiListItemButton-root': {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      minHeight: '100%',
      margin: 0,
      padding: 0,
      fontSize: '62.5%', // makes 1.2rem === 12px, 1.6rem === 16px, ect...
      textAlign: 'left'
    }
  }
}
```

### MUI Html

(????)

```
????
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to get components styled. The last one I describe is specific to MUI and is probably likeliest to be what you are looking for.

Some of the css classes belong to specific MUI components, so you just use the MUI component and if your `<ThemeProvider />` is used correctly, you shouldn't have to add any classes.

You have the option of defining regular CSS or SASS in a separate file and importing it in your component, then using the class via the `className` property of a component.

Another option is CSS-in-JS. You can use the `style` property to use the custom css and you define the CSS in your JS file for the component:

```
... //inside your component
const mystyle = {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue",
      padding: "10px",
      fontFamily: "Arial"
    };
...
    return (
      <div>
      <h1 style={mystyle}>Hello Style!</h1>
      <p>Add a little style!</p>
      </div>
    );

...
```

Above example adapted from https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp

The above work in react without MUI as well. The MUI specific way to create a custom style for a component is to use the `makeStyles()` hook. This will give you variables to use as input to the `className` property but when you inspect and look at the html, the classes applied will have names that are generated by MUI.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});
export default function MyComponent() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

Above example copied from https://react.school/material-ui/styling

To learn more about the `makeStyles()` hook, see the MUI documentation for it: https://mui.com/system/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook
If you scroll on that same page, you can see info about other style related hooks too.

Comment: yeah, I'm using theme already. The question was how do I target the html in css. (inspect browser > Elements > see html)

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding, I have updated my answer, hopefully this answers your question. Let me know if it still isn't quite what you are looking for.